# bash while loop read only one line

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have issue with this code.

```
  while IFS='' read -r line
  do

    echo "host: "$line

    IP_addr=$(echo $line |cut -d" " -f1)
    host=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f2)

    FILE_CHECK=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $USER@$IP_addr "find $SRC_FILE -mtime 0")

    echo $FILE_CHECK

    ((host_num+=1))


    echo "" #empty line
  done < "$SERVER_LIST"

  echo $host_num
```

Where variable server list contain path to file with server

```
192.168.1.1 app1
192.168.1.2 app2
192.168.1.3 app3
```

Script read first line, successfully connect to host and then exit. When I tried loop through file and only echo lines loop read all lines.

Comment: note you can say `while read -r ip host` to directly get the ip_addr and host instead of pulling those from `$line`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh` reads from stdin, so it will eat the rest of the file. Run `ssh` with the `-n` option to redirect its input to /dev/null.